# NextJS Pushing Data to a variable does not actually work

Tags: node.js, next.js

I am trying to push data to a variable containing ids.
this is the code declaring such variable:

```js
var ids = [];
```

I have a element.onclick where whenever they click it, it toggles the selection and decides if it should remove or push a id to the array.

this is the code for that

````js
    function appendImgClick(appendTo, id){
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.setAttribute("class", "thingtopick");
        let img = document.createElement("img");
        img.selected = false;
        img.setAttribute("class", "thing");
        img.onclick = function(e){
            if (img.selected){
                img.setAttribute("class", "thing");
                array_remove_index_by_value(ids, id);
            }
            else{
                img.setAttribute("class", "thing selected");
                addToItemList(id);
                // I've already tried just doing ids.push(id) that did not work, so I used a function that would do that thinking it would be serverside/clientside or something but no.
            }
            img.selected = !img.selected;
        }
        li.append(img);
        appendTo.append(li);
        fetch(`/api/item-thumbnail/${limitedId}`).then(e=>e.json().then(e=>{
            img.src = e.data[0].imageUrl;
        }));
    }
    ```
````

What could I do to make this work?

This whole entire thing is in nextjs (under /pages/select.js) and it is **not** a React Component, its declared like this: ```

```js
export default function page()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I actually figured out my own fix after messing around a little bit more, moving all the functions outside of the export default function page(){} function allowed the list to pass save perfectly fine.

tldr: move the functions outside of the export default function page.